# How to set a specific version of Java as JAVA_HOME in Fish in macOS

Tags: macos, bash, java, fish

I was using Bash as my default shell on macOS but I decided to switch to Fish.

I am trying to switch between different versions of Java. In bash it was done using the `~/.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

I have set the equivalent on Fish `~/.config/fish/fish_variables`

```
set -x JAVA_HOME `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```

Unfortunately, Java version is not being changed. How can I set environment variables (specific version of Java, in particular) using `~/.config/fish/fish_variables`?

#### UPDATE:

According to the [FAQ](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.2/faq.html), instead of `~/.config/fish/fish_variables`, `~/.config/fish/config.fish` should be used. Also I created `~/.config/fish/fish.config` instead of `~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

Comment: The file *~/.config/fish/fish_variables* has no intrinsic meaning to fish. That is, fish won't automatically source the contents of that file.

Comment: @KurtisRader According to FAQ https://fishshell.com/docs/2.2/faq.html I also tried to create ~/.config/fish/config.fish, but it did not help.

Comment: That FAQ says nothing about a file named *fish_variables*. The only fish user config file that is sourced automatically by every fish process is *~/.config/fish/config.fish*. If you put a `echo hello` in that file and start a new fish shell do you see the word "hello"?

Comment: @KurtisRader There was a typo on my side... I have created ~/.config/fish/fish.config instead of ~/.config/fish/config.fish. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kmb But the version with the backticks worked? According to what I have read, they shouldn’t work.

Comment: @kmb You should mark Jake's answer as solving your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I am not deeply familiar with [Fish](https://fishshell.com), based on what I am reading it seems like the issue is with the backticks in your command:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
```

You see that is just like this in Bash:

```
$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)
```

Keep that in mind and look at [this Fish FAQ entry](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-subcommand):

> #### How do I run a subcommand? The backtick doesn't work!
>
> fish uses parentheses for subcommands. For example:
>
> ```
> for i in (ls)
>     echo $i
> end
> ```

Knowing that the config line should most likely be:

```
set -x JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, parenthesis are also not working.

Comment: @kbm You need to provide more information. Saying it's "not working" isn't helpful. If you type that `set -x ...` command interactively what happens?

Comment: @KurtisRader set -x JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7) entered directly to shell works fine. After this action java version is changed to 1.7. After closing and opening terminal again, java is set back to version 11. I want to change it permanently, but I need to keep different version on java installed.

Comment: @kmb Well, my command is just a different version of what you added to `~/.config/fish/fish_variables`. Did you test this variant with parenthesis when it was placed in `~/.config/fish/fish_variables`?

Comment: @JakeGould Parenthesis instead of backticks was one of two errors - thank you for pointing it out. The second thing that was wrong, was the file used by me for configuration. Instead of ~/.config/fish/fish_variables, ~/.config/fish/config.fish should be used. I have updated question with this information.

Answer (score -1):

```
function javaenv
   if test (count $argv) -eq 0
       /usr/libexec/java_home -V
   else
       switch $argv[1]
       case 'ls'
           /usr/libexec/java_home -V
       case 'set'
           set -xU JAVA_HOME (/usr/libexec/java_home -v $argv[2])
       end
   end
end
```

Can put the function above in ~/.config/fish/functions and use it to get the java_home contents with

```
javaenv
```

and set the contents of java_home with

```
javaenv set 1.8
```

Idea and contents taken from [here](https://medium.com/@axross/simple-javaenv-with-fish-shell-287ba4a84ba9)